# Canceling stopping edit session in BeforeStopEditing event of ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, editing, events

I have additional data to be stored when an edit session is saved. If the storing of the data fails (it is located on an internet service) the edit session should not be saved, otherwise data would be inconistant.

Is there a possibility to cancel the stopping of the edit session during the [`IEditEvents2.BeforeStopEditing`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#ieditevents2_beforestopediting.htm) event.

Answer (score 1):

What about working with edit operations?

```
IWorkspaceEdit workspaceEdit = m_featWorkSpace as IWorkspaceEdit;
if (workspaceEdit != null)
{
    try
    {
        workspaceEdit.StartEditing(true);
        workspaceEdit.StartEditOperation();

        //Make your local changes to your workspace
        ...

        //Try to save your changes located on an internet service
        ...

        //if changes are successfully commited to the internet service
        if (changesSuccessfullySaved)
        {
            //database commit
            workspaceEdit.StopEditOperation();
            workspaceEdit.StopEditing(true);
        }
        else
        {
            //database rollback
            workspaceEdit.AbortEditOperation();
            workspaceEdit.StopEditing(false);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I cannot do the whole edit operation in one method. The changes done by the user during an edit session change some data. This data I have to transmit to the internet service before stopping the edit session.

Comment: Are you able to store the IWorkspaceEdit variable as a global member variable? So, you can define it after start editing and reuse it later in a separte method before stop editing an rollback the changes if necessary. Note: This is only reasonable if there are not multiple user working simoultaniously with the same data because of the database locks.